# Hibernate application to insert student details

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have an existing database modeled the following way:

Student - Student ID (int), Student name (String), Gender (String)

CollegeStudent - Semester (String), Grade (String)

School Student - Term (String),Rank(int)

I want to develop a Hibernate Application for the above class diagram to insert student details. 
Note:
Insert 2 objects of type Student, 2 objects of CollegeStudent and 2 objects of School Student.

[image: Image link of class diagram]

Now I am creating hibernate entities for this existing database. And I am running into weird issues creating Many-to-Many mapping from Student to collegestudent and school student.
Any suggestions?`

enter code here`

```java
    import javax.persistence.*;  
    import org.hibernate.annotations.Table; 
    import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
    @Entity  
    @Table(name="STUDENT")  
    public class Student {    
         @Id  
         @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)  


    private int Student_id;

    private String Student_name,Student_gender;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private CollegeStudent collegeStudent;
    public CollegeStudent getCollegeStudent() {
        return CollegeStudent;
    }

    public void setCollegeStudent(CollegeStudent collegeStudent) {
        this.CollegeStudent = collegeStudent;
    }

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private SchoolStudent schoolStudent;
    public SchoolStudent getSchoolStudent() {
        return SchoolStudent;
    }
```

Comment: What kind of weird issues is happening in Many-to-many relationship, please add more details.

Comment: Hello Manali, welcome to stack overflow. Can you provide more information about the weird issues? And also looking at the code, it looks like CollegeStudent and SchoolStudent extend Student class. Can you explain why you have those as class members of a parent class?

Comment: Thanks Charan, Actually I am new to hibernate topic and little bit confused about many to many relationship and many to one relationship, exactly I am not getting which one shall I use?